# Dispose own created Tab

Tags: cefsharp

Hi I have upgrade my application  from 45 to Cefsharp version 71,Earlier new created tab is easily dispose(remove) but now the whole application is shut down,When i am using remove method the tab is closed but it remain in the memory that cause system hanged.

```
public void AddNewBrowserTab(string url, int? insertIndex = null) {
    browserTabControl.SuspendLayout();
    var browser = new BrowserTabUserControl(AddNewBrowserTab, url, UserName, pass, browserTabControl, txtUName.Text.ToString().Trim(), txtUPassword.Text.ToString().Trim(), MUser, TUser);
    var tabPage = new TabPage(url);
    browser.CreateControl();
    tabPage.Controls.Add(browser);
    if (insertIndex == null) {
        browserTabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
    } else {
        browserTabControl.TabPages.Insert(insertIndex.Value, tabPage);
    }
    browserTabControl.SelectedTab = tabPage;
    browserTabControl.ResumeLayout(true);
}

//Call Method
public BrowserTabUserControl(Action<string, int?> openNewTab, string url, string uname, string pwd, TabControl browserTabControl, string loginUsrname, string LoginUsrpwd, string muser, string thuser) {
    InitializeComponent();
    MonsterUsr = monsteruser;
    Techfetchuser = techfetchuser;
    loginUsername = loginUsrname;
    name = uname;
    passwd = pwd;
    txtuname = loginUsrname;
    txtupwd = LoginUsrpwd;
    browserTabControls = browserTabControl;
    var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url) {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    };
    var userControl = new UserControl { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    ZoomIn.Controls.Add(browser);
    Browser = browser;
    browser.MenuHandler = new MenuHandler();
    browser.JsDialogHandler = new JsDialogHandler();
    browser.AddressChanged += Browser_AddressChanged;
    browser.DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler(browserTabControl);
    browser.LifeSpanHandler = new LifeSpanHandler(browserTabControl, ref Browser, loginUsrname, LoginUsrpwd);
    browser.KeyboardHandler = new KeyboardHandler();
}
```

Comment: Where is your code that removes/disposes?

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/cefsharp/71/CefSharp.WinForms.Example contains a working tabbed example.